# Convert a Pandas dataframe to a N-to-1 dictionary, where N columns are keys pointing to a single column as the values

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I'd like to make a single dictionary from a Pandas dataframe where each row from N columns points to the values in a single column, and was wondering if there is an efficient way to do this without having to construct a bunch of for loops and dictionary updates.

For example, is a more programmatic/Pandas'y way to accomplish the following.

```
import pandas as pd
columns = ["A", "B", "C"]
data = [[1, 11, 111],
        [2, 22, 222],
        [3, 33, 333]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=columns)
df

Out[1]:
    A   B   C
0   1   11  111
1   2   22  222
2   3   33  333


mdict = {}
for c in df.columns:
    mdict.update(dict(zip(df[c], df['A'])))
mdict

Out[2]:
{1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3, 11: 1, 22: 2, 33: 3, 111: 1, 222: 2, 333: 3}
```

I'm ultimately trying to create a long dictionary of keys all pointing back to the same value so that I can go to another dataframe and apply the map function to standardize the entries. Is this dictionary step even needed, or is there a simpler way to accomplish this without having to go through an intermediate dictionary? Thanks!

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=[1, 11, 111, 2, 22, 222, 3, 33, 333], columns=['D'])
df2['D'] = df2['D'].map(mdict)
df2

Out[3]:
    D
0   1
1   1
2   1
3   2
4   2
5   2
6   3
7   3
8   3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way of doing this would be:

```
g = df.set_index('A', drop=False).unstack()
m = dict(zip(g.values,  g.index.get_level_values(1)))

m
{1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3, 11: 1, 22: 2, 33: 3, 111: 1, 222: 2, 333: 3}

df1.D.map(m)

0    1
1    1
2    1
3    2
4    2
5    2
6    3
7    3
8    3
Name: D, dtype: int64
```

---

In a similar manner, you can pass a `pd.Series` object to map.

```
s = pd.Series(g.index.get_level_values(1), index=g.values)
s

1      1
2      2
3      3
11     1
22     2
33     3
111    1
222    2
333    3
Name: A, dtype: int64

df1.D.map(s)

0    1
1    1
2    1
3    2
4    2
5    2
6    3
7    3
8    3
Name: D, dtype: int64
```

Comment: @StuckOnDiffyQ Great! Don't forget to vote on it and accept. Thanks.